# How void pointer arithmetic is happening in GCC

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

```
int main()  
{  
    int a;  
    void *p;  
    p = &a;  
    printf("%ld\n",(long)p);  
    p = p+1;  
    printf("%ld\n",(long)p);  
}
```

In this program, `p+1` is just incrementing the value of p by 1. I know `void pointer arithmetic` is not possible in `C`, so `GCC` is doing it implicitly. And if yes, then is it taking it as `char pointer`. Also, why `dereferencing` is not possible for void pointer, if it is implicitly doing pointer arithmetic.

Comment: What do you expect the result of dereferencing a void pointer to be?!

Comment: Also, what's the question? You already noticed that GCC implements void pointer arithmetic like char pointer arithmetic, so what exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C does not allow pointer arithmetic with `void *` pointer type.

GNU C allows it by considering the size of `void` is `1`.

From *6.23 Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers*:

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html

Now to answer this question:

> Also, why dereferencing is not possible for void pointer, if it is implicitly doing pointer arithmetic.

GNU C allows pointer arithmetic with `void *` but still does not allow an object of type `void` to be declared.

Comment: then why dereferencing is not allowed in GNU C?

Comment: As far as GCC is concerned, when we write just *p this statement is removed as a part of optimization step. So actually dereferencing does not take place..If i write int x  = *p; then it gives an error

Comment: The real reason why you cannot dereference a `void *` actually involves lvalues, `void` is an incomplete type and lvalues cannot have an incomplete type.